# How to fix php mailer certificate

Tags: phpmailer

I am trying to use PHPMailer class to send emails from my godaddy VPS, but I get the error below.

Please note that VPS is with a different service provider and smtp email service is with a different service provider.
Sort of like trying to send emails via gmail, but instead of gmail, I am using a different email smtp service provider.

If I comment the mail->isSMTP line, then mail goes, but its going via my own server's sendmail program, not via smtp. That's not what I want.

```
SMTP response is this:
2023-03-31 02:18:42 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`ns1.tbrjar.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.tbrjar.com'

//My code is this:
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // 0 = off (for production use) - 1 = client messages - 2 = client and server messages
$mail->Host = "smtp.tbrjar.com"; // use $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
$mail->Port = 587; // TLS only
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // ssl is depracated
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $smtpUser;
$mail->Password = $smtpPass;
$mail->setFrom($emailFrom, $emailFromName);
$mail->addAddress($emailTo, $emailToName);
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->msgHTML("test body"); //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__); //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
$mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported';
// $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png'); //Attach an image file

if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in another question.
Looks like this is not a phpmailer or smtp error at all. It is a WHM/CPANEL restriction.
WHM is not allowing users to connect to remote smtp.

One can disable the restriction by searching "smtp restriction" in WHM, it will show a link to smtp restrictions settings.
Open those settings and click the disable button to disable the restriction.
Then run your phpmailer code and it works.
I only wish I could have found this yesterday.
Thanks

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. Blocking outbound SMTP would result in `connection refused` errors. Here the connection is succeeding but you're getting a certificate name mismatch, which suggests some other configuration problem.

Comment: This was the problem, and disabling smtp restrictions solved it. I found that answer in another of stackoverflow questions after posting this one. I also found it weird because connection got made, but authentication kept failing when I was using another smtp class, and then when I used PHPMailer, it showed me this error.